# Matrix representation in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to write a program implementing matrix using NASM. As a beginner, I try to rewrite the following C code in NASM.
The C Code:

```
    for(i = 0 ; i< 3; i++){
        for(j = 0 ;j < 3; j++)
            a[i][j] = 0 ;
    }
```

My following implementation of NASM code is:

```
    section .data
          msg db "%d"
          four dd 4
          spce db " ",0
          nl db 10
    section .bss
          arr1 resd 4
          arr2 resd 4
    section .text
          global main
          extern printf
    main:
          nop   
          xor ecx,ecx
          xor eax,eax
          xor ebx,ebx
   lp1:                                 ;to implement "for(r = 0 ; r < 4; r++)"
          mov ebx, arr1
          mov eax,ecx
          mul dword[four]   
          add ebx,eax   
          cmp ecx,4
          jl entryOflp2
              jmp done
   entryOflp2:                           ; to implement for(c = 0 ; c < 4; c++)
          push ebx
          push ecx
          xor ebx,ebx
          xor edx,edx
   lp2:
          mov ebx, arr2
          mov eax,edx   
          mul dword[four]
          add ebx,eax

          mov dword[ebx],0              ; to initial a[r][c]=0
          inc edx
          cmp edx,4
          jl lp2
   endOflp2:
          pop ecx
          pop ebx

              inc ecx
          cmp ecx,4
          jl lp1
    done:
              ret
```

But I found that my program is failed in a inifinite loop  and most notably value of edx is not incrementing. As a beginner, I have few doubts that whether I should implemet a matrix in this way or not.

I am looking for advice from the mentors. I am using UBUNTU 11.04 OS.

### Update of my question:

Following mentor Brendon's advice , I change the above code in following way;still i don't get my desired output:

```
   section .bss
     arr1 resd 9    
   section .text
     global main
     extern printf
   main:
      nop   
      xor ecx,ecx
      xor eax,eax
      xor ebx,ebx
      mov ebx, arr1
   forI:
      xor esi,esi
      cmp ecx,3
      jl forJ
      jmp print
   forJ:
       cmp esi,3
       jl initialization
       inc ecx
       jmp forI
   initialization: ; it will give base address+4(number 
                   ;of colums*rowIndex+columIndex).  
                   ;ecx=row index,esi=column index; I am using Row major represntation
       mov eax,ecx
       mul dword[three]
       add eax,esi
       mul dword[four]
       add ebx,eax        
       mov dword[ebx],0       ;set a[i][j]=0

       inc esi
       jmp forJ
    print:
       xor ecx,ecx
       xor eax,eax
       xor ebx,ebx
       mov ebx, arr1
   forI_2:
       xor esi,esi
       cmp ecx,3
       jl forJ_2        
       jmp done
   forJ_2:
        cmp esi,3
        jl print_task
        pusha
        push nl
        call printf
        add esp,4
        popa
        inc ecx
        jmp forI_2
    print_task:
        mov eax,ecx
        mul dword[three]
        add eax,esi
        mul dword[four]
        add ebx,eax 
        pusha
        push dword[ebx]
        push msg
        call printf
        add esp,8
        popa
        pusha
        push spce
        call printf
        add esp,4
        popa    

        inc esi
            jmp forJ_2
    done:
         nop
```

My intended output will be

```
    0 0 0
    0 0 0
    0 0 0
```

But the output comes here is
0123012301230 0 0
Segmentation fault

Still I am looking for your advice. 
THANK YOU.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense: `jl entryOflp2` / `entryOflp2:` You're going to end up at `entryOfLp2` no matter if the jump condition is true or not.

Comment: @Michael: THanx you are following my question.Sry, I mistook typing here. I reedit the portion above. I am looking for the help

Comment: You do not increment `ecx` anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: Thanx. But still not solved. Its stillin infinte loop. I debug the code and found that movement: main-lp1-entryoflp2-lp2-endoflp2-lp1 and edx counter in lp2 is not incrementing. The loop is not wrking for lp2 section, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how the "array of arrays" is defined in C; but from the use of `a[r][c]` I assume you're doing something like:

```
int a[4][4];
```

In memory this would be an array of 16 integers (or 4 groups of 4 integers). In your NASM code you do this:

```
section .bss
arr1 resd 4
arr2 resd 4
```

This is not an array of 16 integers. It's 2 separate arrays of 4 integers. It should be:

```
section .bss
arr resd 4*4
```

The `MUL` instruction multiplies the 32-bit value in EAX by another 32-bit value (4 in your case) and stores the 64-bit result in EDX:EAX. You're using EDX to control the inner loop, and the `MUL` is trashing EDX. This is the cause of your infinite loop (basically, it's doing "loop until the result of 0 * 4 is not less than 0x0000000400000000).

Also note that the multiplication is unnecessary. It's easier to just add "sizeof(int)" to a pointer. For example (using C as psuedo-code) `for(void *c = a; c < (void *)a + 4 * sizeof(int); c += sizeof(int)) { ... }`. In assembly this might look like:

```
    mov edx,arr
.next:

    ...

    add edx,4
    cmp edx,arr+4*4
    jb .next
```

The same applies to the outer loop. For example (combined):

```
    mov ecx,arr
.next1:

    mov edx,ecx
    lea edi,[ecx+4*4]
.next2:

    ...

    add edx,4
    cmp edx,edi
    jb .next2

    add ecx,4*4
    cmp ecx,arr+4*4*4
    jb .next1
```

Of course the nested loop isn't needed either, because you're doing the same thing to each integer in the array of arrays. You could do this instead:

```
    mov ecx,arr
.next1:

    mov dword [ecx],0

    add ecx,4
    cmp ecx,arr+4*4*4
    jb .next1
```

This can be simplified again - it could just be `memset()` in C; or something like this in assembly:

```
    mov edi,arr     ;es:edi = address of array of arrays
    mov ecx,4*4     ;ecx = size of array of arrays (16 integers)
    xor eax,eax     ;eax = value to fill the integers with
    rep stosd       ;Fill the array
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice. I modify the above code following your advice. Yet, it does not print the desired output. I reedit my question for your kind attention. I am looking for your help.